# Can't connect to remote MongoDB from Gradle, even if I can connect from command line

Tags: java, mongodb, gradle

I have a remote MongoDB that I need to connect to. I have all the credentials, but when trying to connect from gradle with `this.mongoClient = MongoClients.create(dbConnectionString);`, I get following error:

```
java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.disconnect(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:136)
        at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.disconnect(DatagramSocket.java:393)
        at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.doUdpQuery(DnsClient.java:437)
        at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.query(DnsClient.java:214)
        at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.query(Resolver.java:81)
        at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_getAttributes(DnsContext.java:434)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:235)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:141)
        at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:129)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:171)
        at com.mongodb.internal.dns.DefaultDnsResolver.resolveAdditionalQueryParametersFromTxtRecords(DefaultDnsResolver.java:114)
        at com.mongodb.ConnectionString.<init>(ConnectionString.java:381)
        at com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:61)
        at io.my.package.dbsetup.DatabaseService.<init>(DatabaseService.java:28)
```

When I print the `connectionString` and run `mongo $connectionString` in terminal, I can connect with no problems. Even MongoDB Compass works. *It's just Gradle that doesn't*.

My colleague with Ubuntu (I have a Mac) can connect with no issues when running the same code. What could be causing this? Firewall is off.

Comment: The MongoDB Java Driver [Installation with Gradle Dependency](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/getting-started/installation/).

Comment: Already in the dependencies, 4.1.1 (other versions don't work either)

Comment: @Milan Smolik could you please provide the Java and MongoDB version you're working with in your entry post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to use different Java version - 16 didn't work, but I had luck with 8

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).